# Proof explanation to see that subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not path connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation, connectedness, path-connected

Consider the following example from http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-connected-not-locally-connected-space/ .

The part that I don't understand it's the bold text. What is $\arg⁡(B)$?
And why $\arg⁡(1,1)$ is an isolated point of $\arg⁡(B)$?

I greatly appreciate any assistance you may provide.

> $$A = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} [(0,0),(1,\frac{1}{n})] \text{ and } B = A \cup (\frac{1}{2},1]$$
>
> For the proof that $B$ is not path connected, suppose that $\gamma$ is a path joining the point $(3/4,0)$
>   to the point $(1,1).$ We denote $\arg \gamma(t)$ the angle of $\gamma (t)$ with the $x$-axis. $\arg \gamma(t)$ is a continuous function of $t \in [0,1].$ Hence it range is connected.
>
> **This is in contradiction with the fact that $\arg⁡(1,1)$ is an isolated point of $\arg⁡(B).$**

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189)
I have tried to improve the readability of your question by enhancing your
[$\rm \LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: @GNUSupporter it's correct, thank you.

Comment: While the idea behind the proof is reasonable, since $\operatorname{arg}$ is not defined at $(0,0)$, the argument is not complete.

Comment: Your specific question aside, I’m puzzled by something else: The function arg is not defined for the point $(0,0)$, so arg $\gamma(t)$ is not necessarily continuous (or even defined for all $t$) as a function of $t$. It seems like a different argument (pun not intended) provides a proof. If $\gamma(t)$ is a path joining $(3/4,0)$ to $(1,1)$, it must pass through $(0,0)$ to avoid the range problem. But how did it get there from a point on the $x$-axis not near $(0,0)$?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a figure.  I hope it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

[image: A connected but not locally connected set]
[source code of the figure](https://git.io/vNyqb)

$$\arg(B) = \left\{ \mbox{set of all possible angles of oblique lines} \left[ (0,0),\left( 1,\frac{1}{n} \right) \right] \mid n \in \Bbb{N} \right\}$$

One easily observes from the above figure that the angle $\dfrac\pi4$ is an isolated point of $\arg(B)$.

## Detailed Explanation

Note that $$\arg(B) = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} \left\{ \arctan\frac1n \right\} \cup \{0\}.$$
Observe that $\arctan$ is a continuous function, so that $$\arctan\frac1n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} \arctan 0 = 0.$$
The first oblique line $[(0,0),(1,1)]$ and the set difference between $B$ and this oblique line
\begin{align}
&\quad |\arg(1,1) - \arg(B \setminus [(0,0),(1,1)])| \\
&\ge \arctan 1 - \arctan\frac12\\
&= \frac\pi4 - \arctan\frac12 \\
&\approx 0.322 \tag{cor. to 3 sig. fig.}\end{align}

Comment: When you write, $$\arctan\frac1n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} \arctan 0 = 0.$$ Is this the same as, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\arctan\frac 1n = 0$$?

Comment: @user477343 yes, I used the former due to its flexibility when it comes to different types of convergence (in norm, weak, etc).

Answer (score 3):

The proof needs a little tweak to avoid the issue of $\operatorname{arg}$
not being defined on all of $B$.

Let $I= ({1 \over 2} , 1] \times \{0\}$.
Let $t_0 = \sup \{ t | \gamma(t) \in I \}$. We have $[\gamma(t_0)]_1 \ge {1 \over 2}$ and hence there is some $\delta>0$ such that $[\gamma(t)]_1 \ge {1 \over 4}$
for $t \in [0,t_0+ \delta]$. Also, $\gamma(t) \in A$ for $t > t_0$ and
$\gamma(t_0) \in \overline{I}$.

For $ x\in [{1 \over 4} , \infty) \times \mathbb{R}$ define
$\alpha(x) = {x_2 \over x_1}$ (a proxy for $\operatorname{arg}$). Note that
$\alpha$ is continuous.

Note that $\alpha(\overline{I}) = \{0\}, \alpha(A \cap [{1 \over 4} , \infty)) = \{ {1 \over n}\}_n$.

Hence $\alpha \circ \gamma ([t_0,t_0+\delta]) \subset \{0\} \cup \{{1\over n}\}_n$. However, since $\alpha \circ \gamma$ is continuous, the set
$\alpha \circ \gamma ([t_0,t_0+\delta]) $ must be an interval containing
the set $[0, \alpha(\gamma(t_0+\delta))]$ which is a contradiction
since $\{0\} \cup \{{1\over n}\}_n$ contains no non trivial intervals.

Comment: What do you mean with this  notation $[\gamma(t_0)]_1 \ge {1 \over 2}$? $[]_1$?

Comment: @JacobS.: By $[x]_1$ I mean the first component of $x$. A better choice might have been $x_1$, but I was concerned that $\gamma(t_0)_1$ might not be clear.

Comment: Should not be > instead of $\ge$?

Comment: @JacobS.: What are you referring to?

Comment: The same part, $[\gamma(t_0)]_1 \ge {1 \over 2}$

Comment: @JacobS.: I'm not sure I get your concern.